Problema backend - Vercel + Node.js
tengo el siguiente problema:
Ayer 07/08/2024 detecté que desde mi web desplegado tanto el backend como el frontend en Vercel, ha dejado de emitir emails segun la petición de alta, recuperacion de emails, etc etc.
En algunos proyectos este email es enviado desde el servidor de google (hasta hace 1 mes funcionaba correctamente) como desde proveedores externos como ionos, que igual funcionaba.
Desde hace 2 días estoy desplegando otra aplicacion web, con el Stack Mern utilizando nodemailer para la emicion de emails y fue cuando detecté que en producción no se envian emails y no solo con este proyecto, sino con nigúno de mis proyectos más antiguos.
Alguien sabe el motivo? alguna actualización? la información en la web es escaza, ya no se por donde tirar:
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.ionos.es',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    pass: process.env.PASSWORD_HOST,
  },
});

const sendMail = async (to, subject, htmlContent) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    to,
    subject,
    html: htmlContent,
  };

  transporter.verify(function (err, success) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(success);
  });

  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Email enviado a: ${info.response}`);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = { sendMail };


he probado con el puerto 467 y la secure a true, pero tampoco.
En local todo funciona de forma correcta, el problema está en producción.
Gracias comunidad.

y dentro del método sendMail la consola no dice nada? No debiera sendMail devolver una promesa que pudieras debuggear con catch?
